# Drupal: Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object

Tags: php, datetime

I have declared the dates as strings, but these will be inputted by the user using a date picker.

```
function availability_status($updated_node, $start_date, $end_date, $status) {

  // get the fields we need.
    $cid = $updated_node; 
    $sid = $status;
    $from = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d h:i:s", $start_date);
    $to = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d h:i:s", $end_date);

    // change the state to the one selected;
    availability_calendar_update_availability($cid, $sid, $from, $to);

}
```

I get the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\booking\sites\all\modules\contrib\availability_calendars\availability_calendar.inc on line 617" which is...

```
->condition('date', array($from->format(AC_ISODATE), $to->format(AC_ISODATE)), 'BETWEEN')
```

I can't go changing this line, as I want to extend this module, not rewrite it, so there must be something wrong with the way I am setting the date for `$from` and `$to` in the first bit of code.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `var_dump($from, to)` before you pass them into the availability function, see what you ended up with. `createFromFormat` can return a boolean false if the date failed to parse properly.

Comment: string '2016-06-15 16:15:53' (length=19)
string 'to' (length=2)

Comment: `$to`, sorry. and they should have come back as datetime objects, not strings.

Comment: Oops, did you mean $to ? string '2016-06-15 16:15:53' (length=19)
string '2016-06-17 16:15:53' (length=19)

Comment: OK, so when I delete the strings and bring them in using a date field, and use var_dump, I get "int 1466003753
int 1466176553
"

Comment: in which case you're passing unix timestamps into this method, which then tries to parse those ints as if they were strings.

Comment: OK, so they are coming through as unix, I use $test = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_date); to convert them, but now var_dump gives string '2016-06-15 16:15:53' (length=19), why is it giving a string when using date() ?

Comment: that's useless-busywork. datetime can take a unix timestamp directly, so there's no need to format it into a string, and then parse it back again to a timestamp (or whatever datetime uses internally). `date()` will ALWAYS return a string. if they're coming in as timestamps, then you need to look at whatever's calling this method.

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean, but unfortunately thats how the data is provided from the Drupal field. Have solved this now though, thanks for the clues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the date was coming through as a unix time stamp and not a date object.

The working code...

```
function availability_calendars_rules_rules_action_set_availability_status($updated_calendar, $start_date, $end_date, $status) {

  // get the fields we need.
    $cid = $updated_calendar; 
    $sid = $status;
    $from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $start_date);
    $from = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $from);
    $to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $end_date);
    $to = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", $to);

    // change the state to the one selected;
    availability_calendar_update_availability($cid, $sid, $from, $to);

    drupal_set_message('Status has been set to '. $sid);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I found on the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and my intuition, it seems that using double quotes is causing the `createfromformat()` function to return the output as a string. Using single quotes should return it as an object.

Specifically:

```
 $from = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $start_date);
 $to = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s', $end_date);
```

Comment: No didnt work, var_dump($from, $to) gives boolean false
boolean false

Comment: Thats strange. According to the manual I linked, single quotes work fine. Can you try hard coding dates to see if that works?


`$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s',  '2016-06-15 16:15:53');
 $to = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d h:i:s',  '2016-06-17-16:15:53');`

Comment: yeah same boolean false. Hmmm. What am i doing wrong?